# "Fatal Installation Error" in MS Office

Tags: windows, office-2013-preview

I reinstalled windows on my system a while back now i am in need of working on MS Office. I installed the **MS Office 2013 preview**. It installed without a problem but when i try to open Word or Powerpoint or something, one or two configuration windows appear but then nothing, it doesn't open. If i try to open a document or presentation, similar happens but this time it gives a "***Fatal Error during installation***" message.

Now i read some forums and found that i needed to remove MS office and reinstall it. I did it three times and even removed the trace files and registry entries but still the same problem.I even tried the same with **MS Office 2010** a few times, same problem.

I have used the same setups on various PCs, even this one but never before have i faced this problem.

Comment: See if the Fixit tool available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651) helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but it didn't solve anything